# MPMoviePlayerViewController repeat count

Tags: ios, count, movieplayer

I am playing a video using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`.

I have repeat mode as `MPMovieRepeatModeOne` so that the video may play in a loop.

Is there any method that I can use to get the repeat count of the played video.

Comment: did u get the answer?

Comment: Take a look at AVPlayerViewController instead because you may find out a solution for your problem thanks to the new class AVPlayerLooper introduced in iOS10.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(introMovieFinished:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.moviePlayerController];
```

And then use this notification to detect when video finished a loop:

```
- (void)introMovieFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    if (notification.object == self.moviePlayerController) {
        NSInteger reason = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishReasonUserInfoKey] integerValue];
        if (reason == MPMovieFinishReasonPlaybackEnded)
        {
            NSLog(@"Video has looped!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot use the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` with the repeat mode because it will be triggered only if you get out of the video not if you repeat it.

If you use the repeat mode, you will only have a change of state [=> PLAY (end of the former video)... PAUSED (former video)... PLAY (beginning of the new video)] detected thanks to the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification` but the `didFinishNotification` won't be in the loop.

At first sight, you should store previous states of the player to follow this pattern for instance:

1. [stateCurrentTime (PLAY)] > (playingDuration - 1 sec) ==> end of your video
2. [stateCurrentTime (PAUSED)] < 0.5 sec ==> transitional state between former and new video
3. [stateCurrentTime (PLAY)] < 1 sec ==> beginning of your new video.

... And if someone succeeds in finding a way using `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification`, I'll be definitely interested in it because the behavior of this notification doesn't go together with repeat mode.